# NullReferenceException on Sitecore.Data.Eventing.Remote.MovedItemRemoteEvent

Tags: xdb, xconnect, events, reporting

On my 9.0.2 Sitecore Reporting site, I saw this error in the logs:

```
ERROR Exception while handling event Sitecore.Data.Eventing.Remote.MovedItemRemoteEvent
Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Data.DataSource.<Subscribe>b__62_4(Object s, ItemMovedRemoteEventArgs e)
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at Sitecore.Data.Eventing.DatabaseRemoteEvents.OnMovedItemRemoteEvent(MovedItemRemoteEvent event, EventContext eventContext)
   at Sitecore.Eventing.Subscription`1.Invoke(Object instance, EventContext context)
   at Sitecore.Eventing.EventProvider.RaiseEvent(Object event, Type eventType, EventContext context)
```

This was a historical log entry, so I'm unable to tell what the implications were at the time, but given that this error has never been discussed online, I wanted to surface it in case there are security implications.

The error fired 3 times at the exact same millisecond and then never again.

`MovedItemRemoteEvent` is discussed in the Sitecore [docs regarding index update strategies](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/platform-administration-and-architecture/index-update-strategies.html), but otherwise, there isn't much public discussion. Interestingly, this event type isn't mentioned on the 9.0 or 9.1 docs; it is only mentioned in 9.2 and higher.

What could trigger this error?